# Windows Batch taking Wrong credentials to coonect to SQL server in between Execution

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-web-api, windows-services

I have windows batch where i need to connect to physical location in between execution of batch. For that i have configured credentials in app settings. My problem is once batch access physical folder and complete its work, after that i again connect to DB for some purpose but account used for connection is not the one defined in connection string instead of that folder access credentials are being used automatically which gets failed SQL connection error. I m clueless why automatically credentials are being changes. any one has any idea? Below is the app.config details -

```html
<appSettings>
  <add key="ConnectionString" value="server=XXX;database=XXX;User ID=sa;Password=XXX;Persist Security Info=False;"/>
 
  <add key="LOGON32" value="9"/>
  <add key="CrsDataLogin" value="xxxx"></add>
  <add key="CrsDataPassword" value="xxxx"></add>
  <add key="CrsDataDomain" value="xx"></add>
  <add key="ClientSettingsProvider.ServiceUri" value="" />
  <add key="DailyArchieveFolder" value="Archieve//" />
  <add key="WeeklyArchieveFolder" value="Archieve//" />
  <add key="VivisimohttpTimeout" value="100000" />
  
</appSettings>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have your token generated for windows credentials which are trying to connect to db which will fail db connection. Instead of this try to assign both DB as well as physical path access to your app pool account and bypass configured credentials.